# How to modify a variable command in bash without redefining it?

Tags: string, bash, shell, variables

Say I have a variable command `$EXPORT` that is defined as something like

```
EXPORT=$(eval "export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/package1:$PYTHONPATH")
```

However, I want the command to export a new package2 instead of package1 to `$PYTHONPATH`. **Note that I want to do it by modifying the current `$EXPORT` variable instead of redefining it.** What I have tried is to replace the string `"/path/to/package1"` by `"/path/to/package2"`:

```
echo ${$EXPORT//"/path/to/package1"/"/path/to/package2"}
```

but I am getting "bad substitution" error.

So what is the proper way to modify a variable command in bash?

Comment: `export` doesn't print anything. What do you think you're assigning to `$EXPORT`?

Comment: I suspect what you mean is `EXPORT='export "PYTHONPATH=/path/to/package1:$PYTHONPATH"` and then `eval "$EXPORT"'`

Comment: You need to escape the `/` characters inside the `/path/to/package1` and `/path/to/package2`

Comment: @Barmar OK maybe it's a bad example. The simplest example would be `mycmd=$(eval "ls ./")`, and then if I want to `ls` parent directory instead of current directory, if I do `echo ${$mycmd//".\/"/"..\/"}`, I am still getting `bad substitution`.

Comment: As soon you hit enter on `mycmd=$(eval "ls ./")` your system will run: `eval "ls ./"` and return the output which will be the contents of the current directory. That's all that will be stored in `mycmd`, you can't `eval` once again, as the eval has already occurred. You could store the string literal `"ls ./"` in a variable called `mycmd` and then `eval $mycmd`, then change `$mycmd` and `eval $mycmd` once again and get a different output. I think you are thinking of this backwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't store code in variables, Variables are for storing data, functions are for storing code. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050.

I **think** you might want this (untested):

```
do_export() { export PYTHONPATH="${1:-/path/to/package1}:$PYTHONPATH"; }

mycmd() { ls "${1:-./}"; )
```

which you'd then run as `do_export '/path/to/package2'` to prepend `package2` instead of `package1` to `PYTHONPATH` and `mycmd ..` to run `ls` on the parent dir for example.